# renaming xcode project generates signing error

Tags: ios, xcode

(new to xcode. need to change working project) I want to rename my xcode project, followed the instructions in https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/dev3db3afe4f

but if I change the `Identity|BundleIdentifier`, The `Signing` section warns that "The provisioning profile does not match the ... bundle ID"

Where do I add new BundleIdentifier and how do I use it?

(my xcode version is 10.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [If the provisioning profile App ID doesn't match the bundle ID](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev01865b392):

> If there is a conflict between the [App ID](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev618af4e67) in the provisioning profile
>   and the [bundle ID](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev9b66ae7df) in your project, you receive error messages similar
>   to the following:
>
> Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'MyApp Profile' specifies the
>   Application Identifier 'com.mycompany.MyApp.*' which doesn't match the
>   current setting 'com.mycompany.MyApp' In the [project editor](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devdab46c612), choose
>   the target and click General.
>
> In the Identity section, [set the bundle ID](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/deve21d0239c) to match the App ID.
>
> In the Signing section, verify that the team, provisioning profile,
>   and signing certificate settings are correct.
>
> Next to the provisioning profile, click the information icon.
>
> In the dialog that appears, verify that the provisioning profile
>   contains the correct App ID.
>
> In addition, you can view the App ID and provisioning profile details
>   in your [developer account](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devbbdb0a993).

The Xcode default is to generate a profile per app (ie. com.mypackage.myapp)

You can generate provisioning profiles for a package (ie com.mypackage.*), but this may require a paid developer account and may also require selecting it in the app settings.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will try to continue from there. I probably need to generate additional provisioning profile